# Inequality graph concept

Tags: graphing-functions

The inequality is:  $8-3x \le -4$.  Very straightforward.  Solution is $x \ge4$.  Perfect.

Then the problem says to graph this inequality using the line $y=8-3x $ and $y=-4$ and show that these 2 lines produce the validity region of $x \ge4$.  These two lines intersect at $(4,-4)$.  However, when I graph these two lines I do NOT see that it creates a validity region of $x \ge4$.  For example, the point $(4.5,-6)$ contains an $x$ value that is $\ge 4$ and is to the left of the line,  and the point $(5,-6)$ has an $x$ value that is $\ge4$ and is to the right of the line.

How do I show the validity region using those 2 lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for which $x$, the line $y=8-3x$ is under the horizontal line whose equation is $y=-4$.

You will see that $x$ must be $\ge 4$.

Comment: Is there a shaded region?

Comment: Where the red line is under the blue.

Comment: So, an area under $y=-4$ and to the right of $y=8-3x$?  but that region that I just described does not include $(4.5,-6)$ which should be a solution.

Comment: It is not an area. You look for which $x$ the red is under the blue line. the answer is $x\ge 4$.